# Place for repository contract / interface and implementation

Tags: c#, interface, persistence, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Help to understand deeper, there are contract / interface for repository

```
public interface ICoolRepository
{
    Entity GetById(int id);
}
```

where shoul it be declared in domain, infrastracture or app module?

Can repository interface be used in entities like that:

```
public class User
{
...
  public DoStuff(ICoolRepository repo)
  {
    //here goes using cool repository
  }
...
}
```

**where can it be used with no problem? please, give reasones for that**

Comment: Actually you should think about the reasons why you want a repository inside a domain entity. Does a repository defines the entity? Think about separation of concerns.

Comment: @MikeSW in some cases entity should work with collection, so what i need to know: can i use repository interface as collection in entity or should move it to some service, should it be domain, infrastracture or application service?

Comment: If "should work"" means there is a behaviour that needs a collection then that collection should be a parameter of the method. You decide if that collection is a repository or a result of another service. It depends on the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interface should be defined in Domain Model, as it is a part of Ubiquitous Language (it expresses, what is an aggregate and what is not, it expresses the ways the aggregates should be looked for which relates directly or indirectly to some use cases). The implementation of the repository should go to Infrastructure as it contains DAL/ORM references.

It is rather uncommon or wrong to use a repository in entities, but your question is too generic to give you any meaningful answer.

Comment: in question comment i was talking about some case, what about them?